# Hide subtitle on QWizard

Tags: qt, wizard

I'm making a program based on QWizard, however I ran into a blunder recently.
Some of the pages of the wizard need to have no subtitle or even title. However when I open these pages I see that the white subtitle field has enveloped the entire page except for the bottom where wizard control buttons are (it's gray as I need).

If I try to set subtitle to a single space, for example, I still get a huge white field at the top that breaks the harmony. Also it makes the title shrink in size.

Is there any way to hide this subtitle on certain pages? And also keep it from shrinking the title?

If that's relevant, I'm writing under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't set a subtitle for page or set an empty one, QWizard considers it as a page without subtitle. Also you can try `wizard->setOption(QWizard::IgnoreSubTitles)` to force ignoring subtitles. However, wizard's appearance depends on its style. Maybe some styles are supposed to look like you described. Try to use `setWizardStyle` to change the style.

Comment: IgnoreSubtitles gives exactly the same result as if I didn't have any subtitle set up.And setWizardStyle doesn't seen to do anything under Ubuntu

Comment: Actually scratch that. I had a piece of code that was triggering the same style without my knowledge. Now it all works fine

Comment: Which style were you using and which are you using now?

Comment: ModernStyle before and ClassicStyle now. Thanks